# How do I test my CustomUserDetailsService?

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, junit5

I have a `CustomerUserDetailsService` class, which is part of an implementation of Spring Boot authentication. I have tested my code manually, and it works correctly, allowing me to successfully log in to my app. However, I am unable to work out how to test the `CustomerUserDetailsService`.

As a unit test, I believe I would need to mock the `userRepository` member variable, but whatever I try in my test fails, the reason being `userRepository` is set to `null`. I've tried adding the `@Repository` annotation to `userRepository` but am told that is not allowed because it is an interface. There's also the fact that `loadUserByUsername` returns an instance of `CustomUserDetails`, which is just an implementation of an interface, so I have no idea how I'd mock that dependency?

I've also tried doing some kind of integration test but had similar issues, probably due to incorrect annotations on the test itself. In an ideal world, I'd prefer a unit test and would be extremely grateful for any guidance as to how to set it up.

These are the relevant classes...

**CustomerUserDetailsService:**

```java
package com.phil.urlshortener.security;

import com.phil.urlshortener.model.User;
import com.phil.urlshortener.repositories.UserRepository;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UsernameNotFoundException;

public class CustomUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {
  @Autowired private UserRepository userRepository;

  @Override
  public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String username) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
    User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

    if (user == null) {
      throw new UsernameNotFoundException("User not found");
    }

    return new CustomUserDetails(user);
  }
}
```

**User:**

```java
package com.phil.urlshortener.model;

import lombok.Data;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Data
@Entity
public class User {
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @Column(nullable = false, unique = true, length = 50)
  private String username;

  @Column(nullable = false, length = 64)
  private String password;
}
```

**UserRepository:**

```java
package com.phil.urlshortener.repositories;

import com.phil.urlshortener.model.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;

public interface UserRepository extends CrudRepository<User, Long> {
  @Query("SELECT u FROM User u WHERE u.username = ?1")
  User findByUsername(String username);
}
```

**CustomUserDetails:**

```java
package com.phil.urlshortener.security;

import com.phil.urlshortener.model.User;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;

import java.util.Collection;

public class CustomUserDetails implements UserDetails {
  private final User user;

  public CustomUserDetails(User user) {
    this.user = user;
  }

  @Override
  public Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> getAuthorities() {
    return null;
  }

  @Override
  public String getPassword() {
    return user.getPassword();
  }

  @Override
  public String getUsername() {
    return user.getUsername();
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isAccountNonExpired() {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isCredentialsNonExpired() {
    return true;
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isEnabled() {
    return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you forgot to use mockito annotation **@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)**.
Here it's the unit test for **CustomUserDetailsService** :

```
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.mockito.Mock;
import org.mockito.junit.MockitoJUnitRunner;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetails;
import org.springframework.test.util.ReflectionTestUtils;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.mock;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.when;

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class CustomUserDetailsService {
    @Mock
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        customUserDetailsService = new CustomUserDetailsService(userRepository);
    }

    @Test
    public void GIVEN_username_THEN_return_user_details() {
        //Arrange
        final String username = "existingUserName";
        final User user = mock(User.class);
        when(userRepository.findByUsername(username)).thenReturn(user);

        //Act
        final UserDetails userDetails = customUserDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(username);

        //Assert
        assertNotNull(userDetails);
        assertEquals(user, ReflectionTestUtils.getField(userDetails, "user"));
    }
}
```